# How to be sure that files are saved in gallery for all Android devices?

Tags: android

According to user reviews, my app dosn't save on their phones (LG4, oneplus phones, android 5.1, Android 6.0)

For Android 6.0 I have solved the problem by using the new permission system.
But how can I be sure that the code actually works 100% on all devices? 
Is there any improvment that can be made?

**This is the onClick method that is run, when the user clicks the save button
But also ask for permission for Android 6 devices**

```
public void saveQuote(View v) {

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        //check if we have permissoin to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

           //This method just create a bitmap of my edittext
            saveBitmap();

        } else {
            //if permission is not granted, then we ask for it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

**This is the code that makes the saving operation:**

```
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

     String filename = "#" + pref_fileID.getInt(SAVE_ID, 0) + " Quote.JPEG";

    //The directory in the gallery where the bitmaps are saved
    File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/QuoteCreator");

    //The directory in the gallery where the bitmaps are saved
    File myDir = new File(root + "/QuoteCreator");

    //creates the directory myDir.
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(myDir, filename);

        try {

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.savedToast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*
        Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
        immediately available to the user.
         */

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: *But how can I be sure that the code actually works 100% on all devices?* there are so many devices and manufacturers who all do their own thing, you're gonna have a hard time doing that

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yeah thats the downside of Android. But I'm open to whatever that can be improved

Comment: I would replace `File myDir = new File(root + "/QuoteCreator")` with `File myDir = new File(root, "QuoteCreator")`. I also recommend `out.getFD().sync()` in between `out.flush()` and `out.close()`. And you should do something to ensure that *you* get to see whatever exceptions get thrown by the file-writing logic, rather than just dumping them to LogCat, which only works for devices that you can directly debug. Use ACRA or your favorite crash-reporting service for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried your suggestion: `File(root, "QuoteCreator")` on my galaxy s7, but it just made the directory name to PicturesQuoteCreator.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought `root` was a `File`. Pass in a `File` as the first parameter (i.e., `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`, without all the string conversion).

Comment: @CommonsWare I just made the changes in the method. Look at the first two lines. Is that a better approach?
and btw. `The out.getFD().sync();` sound like a good thing to have. I added it to ofcourse

Comment: You are defining `myDir` twice (though that may be just a side-effect of the way you made the edit). Also, get rid of the leading `/` from `/QuoteCreator`, as that's specifically what we're trying to avoid. Let the `File` constructor set things up, depending upon whether the device returns a `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` `File` that has a trailing slash or not. The `sync()` call may help with the indexing, as it's possible that `MediaStore` winds up indexing a partial file or something, and that might contribute to your users' problems.

Comment: @CommonsWare but if I remove the slash,  then the pictures is going to be stored in directory named `PictureQuoteCreator` that dont look good, and if remove "QuoteCreator" from string path, they are just going to directory "Pictures"?

Comment: I did not say to "remove "QuoteCreator" from string path". I said to remove **the leading `/` from `/QuoteCreator`**. This leaves you with "QuoteCreator" as the second parameter to the `File` constructor, the way I showed in my original comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare but doing so file make a map/dictonary that has the name "PicturesQuoteCreator" in the gallary, this dont look right. Maybe you could provide your solutions as an answer with a clear example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
//The directory in the gallery where the bitmaps are saved
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/QuoteCreator");

//The directory in the gallery where the bitmaps are saved
File myDir = new File(root + "/QuoteCreator");
```

with:

```
File root=
  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File myDir=new File(root, "QuoteCreator");
```

(note: no `/`, no `toString()`, no `+`)

This ensures that `File` can handle the cases where `root` has or does not have a trailing `/`.

---

Replace:

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

with:

```
out.flush();
out.getFD().sync();
out.close();
```

This ensures all bytes are written to disk before proceeding, particularly before having the file be indexed by the `MediaStore`.

---

And replace:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

with something that will be useful for you in production. This statement logs something to LogCat. It's not even the preferred way of logging something to LogCat (which is using methods on `android.util.Log`, like `e()`). While you can see LogCat on your development machine for your own devices and emulators, you cannot see LogCat on user devices. There may be useful information in these exceptions that you are lacking. Personally, I use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) and its "silent exception" option for recording these sorts of exceptions that I am handling in-app but still want to know about. However, there are plenty of crash-reporting services, and presumably some of them offer an equivalent feature.